# How do I get div content as object

Tags: javascript

I have div content and div contains text like javascript Object.

```
  <div class="data-content">{ title: "Yes", value : 4247, color: "#FC4349", total_votes: "10968", percentage: "39%"}, { title: "No", value : 6721, color: "#2980b9", total_votes: "10968", percentage: "61%"}</div> 

      <script> var data = $('.data-content').text();</script>
```

currently data value is as a string and I want it as object not string. 
Is it possible or any other way to get div content as javascript object?

any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you format it correctly, you could use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: You need to add `[` in front and `]` at the end of your text for this to be valid JSON

Comment: @neelsg Not only. Look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks @hsz, I saw that when I just did a JSFiddle for it. I'm not such a fan of creating code workarounds for incorrect input data (Such as the regex in your answer), but I suppose that will also work and it is nice code

Comment: @neelsg Thanks. Sometimes we have to face an incorrect input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
var data   = $('.data-content').text();
var output = JSON.parse('[' + data.replace(/\b([a-z_]+)\b/g, '"$1"') + ']');
```

What happens here ? Valid JSON format requires keys to be wrapped with apostrophes, so we wrap them with `/\b([a-z_]+)\b/g` regex.

After that we get only objects separated with comma, so we have to wrap it with `[]` to make an array. Since now it's valid for JSON parser and we get expected result.

http://jsfiddle.net/8ubFY/

Answer (score -1):

Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) as in:

```
var transformed = JSON.parse(data);
```

The linked documentation gives details on how to add error handling if your JSON text is invalid. You can also use [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) for better browser support as in:

```
var transformed = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Okay, so your JSON was also invalid, see [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) for documentation of valid JSON objects. I have fixed it up and created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXsgh/1/) to show the correct code.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token t`